# What is the most efficient and best way to implement a bidirectional communication system using Java?

Tags: java, sockets

My problem is the following, I have two servers from which I have to transfer files, in both directions. The transfer is triggered by a file creation event (on respective sides). The problem is one server has a public IP, the other one doesn't.

I have implemented a socket client that sends a file over a socket, and a socket server which receives and saves it. (Working part)

My questions are :  How to keep the socket 'alive' and send some data to the client after a file-system event occured on the server-side ? (Can the server call the client without knowing it's public IP ?)

Can I achieve this with socket technology or should I go for something else like RMI ?

Comment: WebSockets might come in handy.  You can also use Flex (Adobe) framework which allows Data Push.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is not really an implementation issue. The problem is that you want to keep the client without a fixed address. If you had a fixed IP, I suppose there would be no problem. Right? As you probably understand there is no easy way for a computer to be called without having an address.

An option would be to use an middle solution, wrapping your non-fixed IP with a DNS able to refresh. You could use a service like [dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/) to get a domain name which will actually redirect each packet to the real IP. Your router would have to be configured accordingly in order to refresh the IP to the dyndns servers each time it changes.

Another option, would be to use the [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) paradigm which now is part of HTML5. This way, the server would be able to **push** content to the client whenever he wanted it.

All of the above solutions depend heavily on your detailed scenario and I cannot by anyway guarantee that what I suggest is the best solution. Actually, **I would strongly suggest to get a fixed IP which is a lot costless and cleaner solution than the ones I describe.**

Hope I helped!

Comment: The problem is indeed I don't have a public IP address for one of the server, and I can't retrieve the router's IP because the socket server is behind a proxy which filters that information. All I have is the IP of the proxy server obtained from client's first call/connection. Push technology seems to be a good alternative solution, but does it work in a standalone tiny client / server program or do I need a web broswer / a web container ? My solution needs to be really lightweight and I can't ( not allowed for security reasons) to get a fixed public IP for the server in question.

Comment: I cannot assure you that websockets is a good solution. As you understand is a "hacking" of the normal HTML functionality. I suppose you would have to use an HTML5 compatible web server. It is a very distant shot in my opinion... I would not bet on it.

Comment: After all, I don't think  `websocket` is a bad shot. It's full-duplex communication. And is faster and more efficient than conventional long polling methods (and it consumes less on both sides). It seems to be faster than REST web services, AJAX, etc. They say it's the future for real-time interactive client-server (web) applications. I just got into it, it looks quite primitive but works fine. I'm doing some more experiments , before publishing a more detailed answer to this question.

Comment: Regarding performance, don't base your opinion on any posts or opinions. You have to measure it under you real environment, taking your system's peculiarities under account. Therefore, don't adopt conclusions like "web sockets are faster than REST" without **measuring it on your real system** first.

Comment: The underlying technologies are a bit different. REST and AJAX are HTTP protocol based polling methods, with their heavy protocol headers ( which sometimes are useless). On the other hand, with `websocket` you can even create your own protocol, very easily. It's also worth to mention that the `websocket` pong message represents only 2 bytes (vs 200-2000 bytes for http headers). Math says it is more efficient, given the same hardware and conditions.  websocket is about ~ 100-1000 x  lighter , and ~ 3 x faster.